# How can I replace special character in a string with underscores using a Perl script?

Tags: linux, perl

I have a script taking mythtv recorded shows and encoding them in h264 using handbrake. the script is written in Perl.

My questions is how do I replace spaces and special characters with and underscore using perl?

The strings look something like this when output `"Parks and Recreation - S05E01 - Ms. Knope Goes to Washington"`

I would like it to look like this

> Parks_and_Recreation_S05E01_Ms__Knope_Goes_to_Washington

Thanks in advance. I did do some googling but having found anything useful that I can implement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this might do it - notice that you might introduce duplicates if you transform strings like this.

```
my $input ="Parks and Recreation - S05E01 - Ms. Knope Goes to Washington";

$input =~ s/ - /_/g; # Replace all " - " with "_"
$input =~ s/[^A-Za-z0-9]/_/g; # Replace all non-alphanumericals with "_"

print $input;
```

This outputs:

> Parks_and_Recreation_S05E01_Ms__Knope_Goes_to_Washington

**Edit**

Érics comment below is very relevant, here is a slightly better approach that replaces accented characters with unaccented before making substitutions:

```
use utf8;
use Unicode::Normalize;

my $input="La femme d'à côté";
my $result = NFD($input); # Unicode normalization Form D (NFD), canonical decomposition.
$result !~ s/[^[:ascii:]]//g; # Remove all non-ascii.
$result =~ s/ - /_/g; # Replace all " - " with "_"
$result =~ s/[^A-Za-z0-9]/_/g; # Replace all non-alphanumericals with _
print $result;
```

This variant outputs:

> La_femme_d_a_cote

Comment: And if he likes François Truffaut ? "La femme d'à côté" gives "La_femme_d___c_t_". Not very beautiful ^_^

Comment: @ÉricGuirbal: Good point, I've added a better solution that handles accented characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
my $input = "Parks and Recreation - S05E01 - Ms. Knope Goes to Washington";
$input =~ s/\W/_/g; # Replace anything other than letters, numbers and underscore
```

This outputs:

```
Parks_and_Recreation___S05E01___Ms__Knope_Goes_to_Washington
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below:

```
perl -pe 's/[^A-Za-z0-9]/_/g'
```

Tested:

```
> echo "Parks and Recreation - S05E01 - Ms. Knope Goes to Washington"|perl -pe 's/[^A-Za-z0-9]/_/g'
Parks_and_Recreation___S05E01___Ms__Knope_Goes_to_Washington
```